# Can I lock on a copy of a variable of a class instance?

Tags: c#, locking

In C#, class instances are reference types. Does that mean that it's OK to lock on copies of the values returned by `new`? In my case, I have a class with some fields that need locking:

```
class Foo {
    // ...
    private Dictionary<IAsyncResult, string> fReadRequests;
    private Dictionary<IAsyncResult, string> fWriteRequests;
    private Dictionary<IAsyncResult, string> fSyncRequests;
}
```

In a specific method, I need to perform the same operations on all of those fields. So in order to avoid code duplication, I perform the operations in a loop by copying the fields into an array:

```
var dictArray = new[] { fReadRequests, fWriteRequests, fSyncRequests };
foreach (var reqDict in dictArray) {
    lock (reqDict) {
        foreach (var i in reqDict) {
            // Do something with the request.
        }
    }
}
```

Is this safe? Does locking work as intended even if the variable the lock is applied on is a copy of the original?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but the `Dictionary`  stored in `reqDict` *won't* be a copy of the the dictionary, it will be a reference to the original dictionary, so it will work the same as if you duplicated the code for each dictionary.

Comment: In short, yes, your locking should work fine!

Comment: @T.Kiley - so the reference (not the instance) is a copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're never locking the *variable* that holds the reference, you're always locking the *instance*.

In your case you're copying the *reference*, not the *object*, so it's the same objects you're working on that is in those fields.

Locking on those should work just fine.

Just know that:

1. Locking an object does not in any way prevent other threads from accessing the same object. If that other thread *does not lock*, it will waltz right in and change the object oblivious to your lock.
2. Don't lock on objects you don't own, and objects you publish to others. You need to be sure that *your code* is the only one locking that object, otherwise your careful synchronization code might stop abruptly if some other code also holds a lock on it.
3. **Never lock on value types**, even if you have them in an `object` variable. Every time you copy the value type into an `object` variable, you get *a new copy*, which will have its own lock.

To counteract nbr. 2 you usually do this:

```
private readonly object fLockReadQuests = new object();
```

and then lock on that instead.

But again, your assumptions in the question holds.

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty much reassurance from someone with a longer experience in C# than me I was looking for here, and you've provided just that.